# Can not save setting in roaming/local setting

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I need to save the setting in  either roaming or local settings. The problem is when i execute the program it shows that setting are stored with a given key and those setting can be retrieved back as well.
But when i re-execute or execute the same program later, those saved setting are lost. It again creates them!!

Why setting are not getting saved?

To set the setting, i use following code (setting is a string, value is an object)

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Add(setting, value);

ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.Add(setting, value);
```

To retrieve setting, i use following code

```
ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values[setting];
```

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Hello can anybody please help me out............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a blunder by debugging a test method so setting will not be saved permanently. If you execute your App all your setting will be saved with the above simple coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work just fine. Maybe there's a problem in the logic you're using to decide between reading the value and writing a value back.

Try putting something like this at the startup of your app:

```
object settingValue = "InitValue";

if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(settingKey))
{
    settingValue = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[settingKey];
}
else
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[settingKey] = settingValue;
}
```

You basically need to read the setting if it exists or initialize it when it doesn't.

Also, keep in mind that local settings get deleted when the app is uninstalled and reinstalled. Visual Studio sometimes does this when you make change application manifest.

Comment: Yes Damir,
I understood your logic. If exits then replace otherwise add a new one.
but the problem is it shows that setting are stored and i can retrieve the back ONLY during execution time. If i re-execute those setting which got saved in 1st execution time are lost!!

I just can't figure out this problem? Do i need to set any app manifest values or what?

Comment: @Kasun There must be something else affecting your settings. You don't need to do anything special for them to work in between different application runs. I've prepared a [sample app](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10676122/App22.zip) for you demonstrating this behavior.

Comment: Hello Damir,
Yes in fact your code works absolutely fine. The saved data is available even when you run the application next time. I will cross check my configurations once again.
Thanx alot :)

Comment: Hello Damir,
Actually the problem is the folder getting created at C:\Users\Kasun laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\       is getting deleted or removed automatically after the execution.
But it doesn't happen with your sample app.
Can u tell me why the folder getting created doesn't stay permanently? Is there any setting i must do?